# Как проверить введенные данные без обновления страницы? php

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Добрый день.

Написал форму регистрации, и в ней условиями с помощью `php` вывел сообщения об ошибках при вводе в `input` *имя, фамилия, email и т.д* некорректных данных.

Но теперь проблема в том, как сделать этот вывод ошибок моментальным без обновления страницы. Посмотрел плагин `jQuery Validate`, но если его использовать, придется выпилить часть `php` кода, который как раз выводит сообщения о некорректно введенных данных и в этом я разбирался очень долго, т.к. `php` только третий день изучаю, и еще загвоздка в том, что правила корректности ввода `input`-ов были описаны регулярными выражениями в `php`

Посоветуйте как можно решить проблему? Если надо код посмотреть, могу показать

Comment: А почему бы не проверить на стороне клиента с помощью JavaScript или HTML? У HTML элемента input есть атрибут `required`, если поле обязательно к заполнению и атрибут `pattern` в котором Вы как раз и можете указать регулярное выражение для проверки корректности вводимых данных. На сайте caniuse.com можно посмотреть поддержку в браузерах. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: я попробую тогда проверить на стороне клиента с помощью JavaScript. Кстати про атрибут pattern я не знал, спасибо, и да, пробовал с атрибутом required, но из за того, что он без регулярного выражения проверяет я его убрал, сейчас можно будет пробовать с pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только JS. Дело в том, что PHP - это язык, который выполняется во время загрузки страницы (интерпретируется веб-сервером, а не браузером). (Исключения - АЯКС и КОМЕТ,  PHP в сочетании с JS.) Поэтому решение состоит в использовании языков, интерпретируемых браузерами; самое легкое решение - JS (в комплекте с огромным количеством плагинов).

Comment: Появляется новая проблема у меня - я абсолютно не знаю эти языки. С php и mysql только недавно разобрался, вроде бы все сделал, даже понял как в бд отправлять данные со страницы регистрации которую написал. Получается все заново изучать и заново писать? =(

Comment: Все заново не нужно. Просто учить дальше. Без JS в веб-разработке обойтись будет ну уж очень сложно :)

Comment: Было бы обидно все старания выбросить в помойку :) Я бы показал код, можете тыкнуть пальцем где мне правку сделать нужно? Только разобраться бы как тут код скидывать..

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ типа такого

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XuJrSDAK
синтаксис php оставил

Comment: Код в студию ;)

Comment: а вот по ссылке: 
https://pastebin.com/XuJrSDAK 
надеюсь, откроется :)

Answer (score 0):

Отправлять данные на сервер посредством ajax, например, используя jQuery:

```
    var form=$("form");
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     data: form.serialize(),
     url: "?send&ajax",
     success: function(data){
      //data содержит подготовленный ответ от сервера
      if(data=="ERROR"){
       //форма вообще не отправилась
      }else{
       //форма ушла, нужно проверять ответы с формы
      }
     }
    });
```

Comment: Я же могу с помощью PHP это сделать, PHP я более менее понимаю, а с Ajax абсолютно не знаком..

Comment: Данные с формы должны отправляться на сервер, я примерно написал выше как это делается, затем сервер их проверяет и отправляет ответ обратно на страницу. Ответ Вы проверяете и показываете пользователю. Я, например, разделяю **статус||ответ**, например, error||Данный пользователь не найден в системе. Затем на js проверяю ответ от сервера и оформляю его в зависимости от статуса.

Comment: В частности по Вашему коду: если отдаете в ответ что-то, то делаете проверку на аякс, например:

`if(isset($_GET["ajax"])){
echo '<div style="color: green;">Вы успешно зарегистрированы</div><hr>';
}`

а на 86 строке

`}else{ $errors=join("<br />",$errors); echo '<div style="color: green;">{$errors}</div><hr>'; }`